# Как улучшить менюшку в консоли?

Tags: c#

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int i;
        try
        {
            do
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
                Console.Write("1) Первый пункт\n2) Второй пункт\n3) Пока не доступно!\n\n");
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
                Console.Write("Выберите пункт: ");
                i = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine();
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 1: Glas.Geto; break;
                    case 2: Glas.Viser(); break;
                    case 3: Console.WriteLine("0opps");  break;
                    default: Console.WriteLine("Вы что-то другое нажали..."); break;
                }
            }
            while (i != 3);
        }
        catch { }
    }
}
```

Подскажите можно ли как-то улучшить вывод?

Как-то не очень смотрится с `Console.Write("1)\n 2\n")`

Comment: А что не так? Как должно выглядеть?

Comment: @VladD, Я думал что будет как-то оригинальнее и правильнее использовать вывод списка пунктов через `string[] text = {"1) Первый пункт"};` Просто нужен совет)

Answer (score 2):

Для такой простой программы я бы не стал заморачиваться и оставил всё как есть.

Если когда-нибудь вы захотите чего-то реально сложного, например, динамическую систему пунктов, конфигурируемость и ещё какие-нибудь какие-нибудь энтерпрайзные фичи, можно будет обобщить это, создав описатель меню:

```
class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem(string name, Action actionOnCall)
    {
        Name = name;
        ActionOnCall = actionOnCall;
    }

    private readonly Action ActionOnCall;

    public string Name { get; }
    public Execute() => ActionOnCall();
}
```

Теперь ваше меню можно представить в таком виде:

```
IEnumerable<MenuItem> Items = new MenuItem[]
{
    new MenuItem("Первый пункт", Glas.Geto),
    new MenuItem("Второй пункт", Glas.Viser),
    new MenuItem("Пока не доступно!", () => Console.WriteLine("Oops"))
}
```

И код будет выглядеть так:

```
while (true)
{
    var items = Items.ToList(); // имеют право поменяться => фиксируем
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkCyan;
    for (int idx = 0; idx < items.Length; idx++)
        Console.WriteLine($"{i}) {items[i].Name}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{items.Length}) Выход");
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
    Console.Write("Выберите пункт: ");
    int userInput;
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
        userInput = -1;
    Console.WriteLine();

    if (0 <= userInput && userInput < items.Length)
       items[userInput].Execute();
    else if (userInput == items.Length)
        break;
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Вы что-то другое нажали...");
}
```

Я бы сказал, что стало намного сложнее, и так переписывать программу не стоит.

Comment: Хороший пример для подражания), Отличная реализация)